# Is there a way to return a has_many calculated field value from a ruby mongoid query?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

My goal is to avoid multiple database queries and get it all in one hit

I have a document object model called `Sponsor` and it `has_many` `players`

```
class Sponsor
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :players
  field :name, type: String

  # . . .
end

class Player
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :sponsor, inverse_of: :players
  field :name, type: String
end
```

I would like to obtain the number of `players` my `Sponsor` has, but I would like it to be returned within my returned sponsor object by calling a class method on `Sponsor`

```
class Sponsor
 # . . .

  def self.return_all_with_player_count
    # do something to get object with injected player count
  end

end

# Sponsor.return_all_with_player_count => [{name: 'Someone 1', player_count: 2}, {name: 'Someone 2', player_count: 12}]
```

## Edit

Is this something where `scope` would be used in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this implementation, it will return what the method `return_all_with_player_count` expects.

```
  def self.return_all_with_player_count
    all.map do |sponsor|
      { name: sponsor.name, player_count: sponsor.players.count }
    end
  end
```

`scope` is like a filter that is not suitable in this case.